# PrimeNG and Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, primeng

We have used PrimeNG 5.2.x and Bootstrap 4.2.x in our project. However, the PrimeNG component was not displayed correctly. When we removed the reference on `bootstrap.min.css` in file `.angular-cli.json` the PrimeNG components were displayed correctly.

Is there a way to use both together? Is coexistence between PrimeNG and Bootstrap possible?

Thanks

Comment: In a project i worked, we decided to get rid of bootstrap and go with  PrimeNG 's grid, etc. because styling things becomes "dirty" using both.

Comment: using bootstrap 3 and primeNG, all good

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a conflict on the grid, I used primeflex but Bootstrap covered the settings.
Solution: In angular.json, put the priority styles settings (PRIMEFLEX) at the end.

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/mdc-light-indigo/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
          "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"
        ],
```